# Here is the error I keep getting. schema "b" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find the total sales done in every state for customer_20_60 and sales_2015 table.

```
select a.customer_id, a.state, b.sum(sales)
from customer_20_60 as a
inner join sales_2015 as b
on a.customer_id=b.customer_id   
group by a.customer_id;
```

Comment: The aggregate function `sum` is not in schema `b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.customer_id, a.state, 
sum(b.sales) sales_summ
from customer_20_60 as a 
inner join sales_2015 as b on a.customer_id=b.customer_id 
group by a.customer_id,a.state;
```